# Change Date format in tcomb form native

Tags: javascript, react-native, tcomb-form-native

I have date json format like this "YYYY-MM-DD" , so i do this in my tcomb form :

```
dob: {
            returnKeyType: 'next',
            testID: 'dobInput',
            label: 'Birth date',
            mode: 'date',
            error:'',
            config:{
                format: (date) => {
                    return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                  },

            }
```

but the return data still look like this "Sun Mar 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000". So i try to reformat the value with moment when the value is set, like this :

```
const value = this.refs.form.getValue()
    formatDob = moment(value.dob).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    value.dob = formatDob

    console.log(value)
```

But the value still not change to "YYYY-MM-DD". How do i change the dob value format? please help, thankyou before

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope help U

```
const value = this.refs.form.getValue()
    formatDob = moment(value.dob, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    value.dob = formatDob

    console.log(value)
```